# Android Camera JpegPictureCallback with varying input data size problem when takePicture() is called

Tags: android, callback, camera, jpeg

I called takePicture() and pass it a PictureCallback as a JpegPictureCallback. I'm seeing byte[] data input varies in size within onPictureTaken(). Can someone explain why this byte[]'s content size varies? I'm already setting picture size to a constant size with Camera.Parameters.setPictureSize();

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's just because the bytes array is the compressed jpg stream. As usually, jpg images' size vary depending on the image.